# is there an offline installer for lxml?

Tags: python, windows, lxml

I have a Windows 7 machine connected to a private network without internet access.  I need to install lxml on this machine for some scripts I am writing.  Is there an offline installer for lxml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[lxml-2.3](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/2.3) has downloadable `egg` packages for Windows, both 32-bit and 64-bit, and for Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.1, and 3.2.

If you want the latest `lxml-2.3.4`, you can get them from the [University of California Irvine download page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml). There are eggs and normal Windows installers for 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Pythons 2.5 - 3.2.

If you download the `egg` files, you can install them using [`easy_install` from distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute).

```
easy_install /path/to/eggfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Best place for compiled python libraries for windows

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

You won't find better